# SQL SERVER 2019 - LEN(FLOOR(CAST([value] AS FLOAT))) defaulting to 12

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running the following code to get the length of a value before the decimal place:

```
SELECT LEN(FLOOR(CAST([VALUE] AS FLOAT))) FROM TABLE1 WHERE VALUE2 <> 'B'
```

The [VALUE] column in TABLE1 is of type nvarchar(30) hence the cast. The column also contains some non-numeric values but these are filtered out by the WHERE clause as they all have a 'B' value for VALUE2.

The code works as expected and returns '6' for values with 6 digits such as '123456.123'. It also works correctly for values with less than 6 digits. However, the code simply returns '12' for any value with greater than 6 digits such as '12345678'.

I've done some googling and can't seem to find a reason for this? Any explanations / alterations / alternatives would be much appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT LEN(FLOOR(12345678));` returns 8 for me... You need to provide a [mre] here.

Comment: Sure -- that's because `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 12345678e)` is `1.23457e+007`. Use `FORMAT` if you need explicit control over the string representation of floating-point values. Or better yet use decimals.

Comment: Also, be very careful about statements like "these are filtered out by the `WHERE` clause". The optimizer is free to rearrange evaluation of expressions to any place it wants; it is *not* compelled to evaluate the `WHERE` first. There are many instances of people reporting this as a bug, but the optimizer folks disagree. Always play it safe and use `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` if you know your data contains values that won't convert.

Comment: Another reason why not to use `float`/`real` when you want numbers than aren't a floating point value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LENGTH()` function expects string expression, so the float value is implicitly converted to string using scientific notation. The following statement demonstrates this issue and the unexpected result:

```
SELECT 
   LEN(FLOOR(CAST([VALUE] AS FLOAT))), 
   FLOOR(CAST([VALUE] AS FLOAT)),
   CONVERT(varchar(50), FLOOR(CAST([VALUE] AS FLOAT)))
FROM (VALUES
   (N'12345678')
) TABLE1 ([VALUE])
```

Result:

```
12  12345678    1.23457e+007
```

A possible solution, without using an integer (and/or float) conversion, is the following statement:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(N'.', CONCAT([VALUE], N'.')) - 1
FROM (VALUES
   (NULL),
   (N'12345678'),
   (N'123456.123'),
   (N'99999.923')
) TABLE1 ([VALUE])
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am running the following code to get the length of a value before the decimal place:

This value is called the log base 10 plus 1 -- at least for numbers greater than 1.  So how about using:

```
floor(log10(value)) + 1
```

You can tweak this for values less than 1 (including negative values) if that is needed.

Comment: This would be mathematically correct, but of course `log10` is subject to the same problems with floating-point accuracy as any other calculation. `sqlcmd  -S . -Q "SELECT 999.99999999999989e"` will show a value with 3 digits before the decimal place, but `FLOOR(LOG10(999.99999999999989e)) + 1` is 4. As a result this may or may not match what you're after depending on how numbers are formatted client-side; if you need that string manipulation is unavoidable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . That of course is compared to converting a value to a string.